# Have a ViewPager scan through the same instance of a Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have seen lots of examples of how to use a ViewPager to scan through multiple instances of the same Fragment. I don't want to do that. I want to have a single instance of a Fragment that runs off the edge of a screen and use a ViewPager (or at least the nice clean ViewPager swiping effect) to scan through the different sections of the single fragment. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

You can:

- Use nested fragments for the pages in `ViewPager`, or
- Use views for the pages in `ViewPager`, such as in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/MultiView1), or
- Use `HorizontalScrollView` instead of `ViewPager` to wrap around a single wide view

Comment: 1) I don't see how nesting fragments will change anything.

2) This is problematic, because I need this viewpager to show 2 items in the vertical version, but 4 in the horizontal version, which gives me problems in terms of creating/destroying fragments.

3) Yes, a scrollview can work, but it doesn't have that clean motion that automatically finds the end of the page and lands there.

Comment: But, I'll try playing with your second solution to see if I can make it work that way.

Comment: @KairisCharm: "I don't see how nesting fragments will change anything" -- please edit your question to explain **precisely** what "a single active Fragment that runs off the edge of a screen" means. "I need this viewpager to show 2 items in the vertical version, but 4 in the horizontal version" -- which can be accomplished with a `ViewPager` by overriding `getPageWidth()` in your `PagerAdapter`, whether the pages are views or `Fragments`.

Comment: I've been trying to do that, but I can't find a good example of how to use ViewPager with LinearLayouts instead of Fragments. I've done the best I can, but I get an error saying that it can't convert from ViewPager.LayoutParams to LinearLayout.LayoutParams. Any ideas?

Comment: @KairisCharm: Here is a sample app demonstrating non-fragments as pages in a `ViewPager`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/MultiView1 This particular sample happens to be demonstrating showing two pages at once via `getPageWidth()`. It also happens to be using simple `Views` instead of fragments or `LinearLayouts`, but perhaps it will be useful for you.

Comment: Getting warmer (and thank you very much for that!) but when I do my version of this:

    View page=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.page, container, false);

"page" comes out as null. Now, I am working in a fragment, so I'm using getActivity().getLayoutInflater().... But that shouldn't make a difference, should it?

Comment: @KairisCharm: I am not aware that it's *possible* for `inflate()` to return `null`. I do not recall seeing that in over five years of Android development. Hence, I haven't a clue what might cause that behavior, sorry.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. Eclipse was lying to me. Now I'm just trying to figure out why I can't seem to set the fields inside the LinearLayout that I'm inflating. I can't do it in instantiateItem because I download the data at regular intervals.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for your help! Can you share the link to your code in an answer? I'd like to mark it as a correct answer.